# How can I add IEnumerable< T > collection data using redis dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, redis, stackexchange.redis, cachingframework.redis

I tried like following

```
var Settings = new RedisSettings("localhost");
public async void SetData< T >(IEnumerable< T > collection, string Key)
{
    RedisDictionary< object, T > mydictionary = new RedisDictionary< object, T >(Settings, typeof(T).Name);
    //how to add collection data into dictionary
    // i tried like following but failed 
    await mydictionary.Set(new[] { new KeyValuePair< object, IEnumerable< T > >(Key, collection) });
```

but it is not able to insert value into redis dictionary :(
I have used

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but is `RedisDictionary` a `StackExchange.Redis` class? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not seems to be related to `StackExchange.Redis`. It's probably related to `ServiceStack.Redis`.

Anyway if you're looking for handling Redis Hashes as .NET dictionaries with a non-commercial client, like `StackExchange.Redis`, I recommend you to use the [CachingFramework.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CachingFramework.Redis/) library that relies on StackExchange.Redis.

[Here](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/blob/master/CachingFramework.Redis/RedisObjects/RedisDictionary.cs) is the code for the `RedisDictionary` implementation. (see the [documentation](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/blob/master/COLLECTIONS.md#redis-hashes))